# Testing type of convergence of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How the following series converges absolutely or conditionally or diverges:

$$\sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{n^n}{2^n n!} $$

Since it is alternating it is converging right? But I am not sure how to prove absolutely or conditionally.

Comment: Try applying the alternating series test. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Comment: Perhaps even the ratio test?

Comment: See [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Answer (score 2):

Using [the ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test): let 
$$u_n=(-1)^{n+1} \frac{n^n}{2^n n!}$$
we have
$$\frac{|u_{n+1}|}{|u_n|}=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}(n+1)!}\times \frac{2^n n!}{n^n}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^n\sim_\infty\frac{e}{2}>1$$
so the series isn't  convergent.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you did in those last couple of steps.

Comment: Simplify and use that $\left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^n=e^{n\log\left(1+\frac 1 n\right)}\sim e^{n\frac 1 n}=e$

Comment: I indeed was busy today. Nice to see you my bro. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)
$$n! \sim \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2 \pi n}$$

Thus

$$\frac{n^n}{2^nn!} \sim \left(\frac{e}{2}\right)^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi n}}$$

And since $e > 2$, the general term of the series does not converge to zero,  thus the series is divergent.